# On load event is not fired when image is removed and reattached using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to add `load` event to `img` tag when the `src` of the image is changed. The `image` is deleted and reattached due to a plugin, so I can't really changed that. This is my simplified HTML

```
<div class="twitter">
    <img src="picture.jpg" />
</div>
```

And this is my Backbone script

```
var TwiterView = Backbone.View.extend( {
    render : function() {
        var self = this;

        this.$el.on('load', 'img', function() {
            self.updateTwitterPreview();
        }).each(function() {
            if(this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');
        });

        this.$el.find('img').on("remove", function () {
            alert("Element was removed"); // This one got fired when the event is removed
        });
        return this;
    },
    updateTwitterPreview: function() {
        alert('test'); // This one got fired when the page is loaded the first time, but not when the image is changed
    }
});
```

I'm trying to use delegated event but it didn't really work.

Comment: your script is incomplete. Where's the events hash?

Comment: The events is left out because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335702/how-to-delegate-a-load-dom-event that's why I attach the event manually.

Comment: You can't use delegated events without the events hash. You need to rerender your view every time in order to get the event listener attached to your new `<img>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `this.$el` returns the actual image element

For delegated event you should use a parent element

instead of this

```
this.$el.on('load', 'img', function() {
```

try using this

```
$(document).on('load', 'img', function() {
```

here `$(document)` element can be anything which is parent to the `image` elements